# How to append to a jQuery object in order without using a parent $('<div>')

Tags: jquery

While preparing to make some DOM insertions I build an array of jQuery object. For example the options of a select:

```
var options = [];

for (...) {
     var $option = $('<option>')
     ...
     options.push($option);
}
```

This `options` array is used as a template for many selects on the page. So I want to add:

```
$('.target-select').append(...)
```

And I want to make this without having to wrap all options into an additional `$('<div>')` and then get them back with `children()`.

Is it possible to make an empty jQuery object and append to it elements in order and without relying on a parent element and `children` function? (`$.add` does not guarantee order for elements not in DOM)

Comment: `$('YourTarget').html(options.join(''));` ?

Comment: @Dementic I like this one :) Of course the OP could use a string instead of an array in the first place

Comment: An Option object is easy to create and once you have an array of DOM elements you can just use `.append(options);`

Comment: @Dementic I also want to avoid `html()` (serializing and deserializing the elements)

Comment: @Jack append does not work. See the comment to Matteo Tassinari's answer below

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay It does if you create a collection of DOMElements instead of jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DocumentFragment to create DOM fragments to which you can append elements and you can append the fragment to anywhere in the DOM.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
         fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    }
    $('#target').append(fragment);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

following code seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/75kVb/5/

```
var options = [];

for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
     var $option = $('<option/>')
     $option.text(i);     
     $('.target-class').append($option);
}
```

you can make an empty select...

```
var $select = $('<select/>');
var options = [];

for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
     var $option = $('<option/>')
     $option.text(i);     
     $select.append($option);
}

$select.appendTo('body'); // not a must, just to prove that it works.
```

and to get them back:

```
console.log($select.find('option'));
```

or, you could just use the array as a simple array (not `<option>` array), with values
then you could:

```
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    options.push(i);
}

var newOptions = $.map( options, function( item ) { // take every second item
  if (item % 2 == 0)
      return '<option>' + item + '</option>';
});
```

example of use to populate a select:
    `$select.html(newOptions);`

Comment: This is not what I do. I do not append them to DOM. I just keep an array of `<option>` references for later to be cloned. This solution is also less efficient if `$('.target-class')` is an in-DOM element because DOM accesses are much more costly than the in memory ones. And to clone them later you must have a jQuery object, not an array. That is why I want to append to a jQuery object.